# It seems strange to get object values from "spring"

Tags: java, spring, jsp

```
    obj = {"A":"A","B":"B"};
    $.ajax({
        url : "blur",
        data : {
            "aaa":obj
        },

        type : 'POST',
        success : function(result) {
            console.log("data : ",result);
        },


    });
    @RequestMapping(value="blur.do")
    public ModelAndView aa(@RequestParam HashMap<String, 
    Object>dto) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    log.debug("********** map: " + dto); 
    // dto.get("aaa") -> error
    // dto.get("aaa[A]") -> A
    return mav;
}


"********** aaa: dto : {aaa[A]="A",aaa[B]="B"}
```

Like the source above, I passed the value using "ajax".

But it looks like this:

The result I want is {aaa={"A","B")}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var obj; 
obj = {"aaa":{"A":"A","B":"B"}};
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj["aaa"]);
console.log(obj["aaa"]["A"]);
```

output :

> Object { zzz: Object, aaa: Object }
>
> Object { A: "A", B: "B" }
>
> A